# German umlauts issue while insert into mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql

Basically i am working on a german project.
am facing some problem while inserting data into database as database doesn't support German umlauts.

lets say for the example

case1: front end want to insert "Dhrubàjyőti" it looks like "DhrubÃ jyÅ‘ti" on database without using any function while inserting.

case2: front end want to insert "Dhrubàjyőti" it looks like "DhrubÃ jyÅ‘ti" on database with using `mysql_real_escape_string()` while inserting.

case3: front end want to insert "Dhrubàjyőti" it looks like "Dhrub**&Atilde**;**&nbsp**;jy**&Aring**;‘ti" on database with using `htmlentities()` while inserting (I have highlighted the bold word, as stackoverflow editor convert it as special charecter).

I want the data should be insert like "Dhrubàjyőti" original as it is.

Need some proper solution.

Comment: Read: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: i have checked, but the problem yet not solved.

Comment: Then you have not read enough yet.

Comment: i have checked my database as the tutorial says, i have checked my HTML. all is fine according to the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

That is quite interesting, since we Germans not use the mentioned example word alot (...).

But for your problem, when your database does not support umlauts (latin1 or utf8/unicode...), then you are lost and have to store it encoded and decode after selecting.